# How would I write a bean to a JSP without it automatically adding a space character after whatever it writes?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, javabeans

I want to format a name as follows:

> First M. Last

The issue is that `bean:write` automatically puts a space after whatever it writes, so I end up with

> First M . Last

Is there anything I can do to avoid this issue?

Code snippet:

```
<bean:write name="secureSearchResultsDetailForm" property="createdBy.firstName" />
<bean:write name="secureSearchResultsDetailForm" property="createdBy.middleName" />
.&nbsp; 
<bean:write name="secureSearchResultsDetailForm" property="createdBy.lastName" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. You have to put things on the same line of code if you want to put it before the space. I change my code to this:

```
<bean:write name="secureSearchResultsDetailForm" property="createdBy.firstName" />
<bean:write name="secureSearchResultsDetailForm" property="createdBy.middleName" />.
<bean:write name="secureSearchResultsDetailForm" property="createdBy.lastName" />
```

and now it works.